# How to solve "Cannot find module '../definitions/exclusiveRange" in react

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

When i try to start 'npm start' in react app it shows "Cannot find module '../definitions/exclusiveRange".How to solve this in react version": "0.1.0".

Comment: Did you run npm install?

Comment: Yes i run npm install

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.